# how to create a button to do some function in xpce/prolog

Tags: swi-prolog, xpce

```
?- new(B, button(hello,
                 message(@pce, write_ln, hello))).
```

In xpce/prolog, this the way to create a button to print a sentence
is there any way that when i click a button i want to do some function, please help!

Answer (score 3):

from `Help > XPCE manual > Browsers > Examples > Obtainers` + Right Click + `Select` you can see a practical example.

```
create_person_dialog :-
    new(D, dialog('Enter new person')),
    send(D, append, new(label)),    % for reports
    send(D, append, new(Name, text_item(name))),
    send(D, append, new(Age, text_item(age))),
    send(D, append, new(Sex, menu(sex, marked))),

    send(Sex, append, female),
    send(Sex, append, male),
    send(Age, type, int),

    send(D, append,
         button(create, message(@prolog, create_person,
                                Name?selection,
                                Age?selection,
                                Sex?selection))),

    send(D, default_button, create),
    send(D, open).

create_person(Name, Age, Sex) :-
    format('Creating ~w person ~w of ~d years old~n',
           [Sex, Name, Age]).
```

After open highlight `create_person_dialog`, right click and `Consult` should get (I filled some value)

[image]

and clicking `Create` output in console

```
Creating male person goofy of 99 years old
```

Generally you need to `attach` your buttons to some GUI to get their functionality.

HTH

**edit** here the layout I get on Windows

[image]

there is a difference in the *way* those 2 images are obtained: in Windows I have the context menu `Consult` active after opened the help topic.

Comment: With Windows 7 I don't get this design of dialog, what OS do you use ?